# My flyway scripts not rolling up

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, flyway

I'm following this tuttorial:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

I'm putting sql scripts in '${project}/src/main/resources/db/migration/v1.0.0__initialization.sql' 
but got 'flyway schema is up to date. no migration necessary' message. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess because you use '/' in your file path you are using unix/linux.
Unix-like systems are filename case-sensitive. Try to rename your script to '${project}/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1.0.0__initialization.sql'
Pay attention to big/capital ***V***

Comment: the elusive capital V was the issue for me (I had lowercase v) - thanks for pointing it out